# Needed advice on how to implement js/css versioning

Tags: javascript, version-control, web

so I am implementing this js/css versioning scheme, where  I basically append a checksum of the js/css file. The strategy which I am thinking of is, basically get this checksum value, then compute the checksum of the file(which I presume may come from the cache), if they match, then the client has the latest files, if not then the client browser will force download that particular file from the server. Is this approach correct?
Also I wanted to understand the behavior of the script tag, like will the src attr of the script tag, go to the cache first for the js file or to the webserver directly?

Thanks

Comment: Won't appending the checksum of the file to the file change the checksum of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's actually simpler in real-life scenarios. You append some unique checksum to the JavaScript file *name* (you don't change the file itself) and you use that full name in your HTML files. Also when the browser requests for this `.js` file you use far in the future `Expires` header (typically one year) so that the browser caches this file "*forever*". Take a look at the source of the web site you are now using:

```
<script src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=aa8b9e2e0673" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=ffb907d7e663" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

(SO uses technique described here by *@machineghost*).

As long as you don't change the `.js` file, its checksum and file name are the same and the browser is not doing anything. The file is cached and you said it won't change within a year. So how do you change it? Well, every time you modify the file, checksum changes. The browser sees a differen `.js` file and is forced to download it. The previous file is useless but the browser will keep it for one year (we don't care).

This way you can combine aggressive caching and rapid changes (no problems with browser caching old JavaScript but using new HTML, etc.)

> src attr of the script tag, go to the cache first for the js file

Yes, if this JavaScript file was already downloaded, browser will use cache. This is actually a bit more complicated. If you returned `Expires` header last time, browser won't even touch your server. If you only returned `Last-Modifed` header, browser will issue so-called *conditional GET* - server will only return new contents if the file changed and `304 Not Modified`  otherwise.

Comment: "The previous file is useless but the browser will keep it for one year (**we don't care**).". Haha, now I understand why browsers' cache is so huge...

Comment: @Oriol: well, the caches aren't growing infinitely. Every good browser will let you customize the maximum cache size and use some heuristics to remove oldest/least used items.

Answer (score 2):

Tomasz hit the nail on the head ... except there's an even easier solution :-)  Don't change the file name of your files at all; just change the link to them, specifically the "search" part.  And you don't really need a checksum, you can also use an incrementing number or the current revision number in your source control system

So in other words:

```
<script src='myFile.js'/>
```

would be:

```
<script src='myFile.someChecksum.js'/>
```

as Tomasz described it; if instead you do:

```
<script src='myFile.js?x=someChecksum'/>
```

the browser will still consider it a new file (when the checksum changes), but you won't have to change the file name everytime.  If you use the revision number, you don't even have to compute a checksum everytime, you just need server-side logic to the effect of:

```
<script src='myFile.js?x={{currentRevisionNumber}}'/>
```

Comment: +1, just noticed SO-guys are using this approach as opposed to changing file name.

Comment: Ok, thanks a million. But i wanted to know, wont the logic be the same that I have mentioned in the question itself, and hence wont it be client-side?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the logic"; there is both server- and client-side logic involved.  On the server-side, you need your server code (Python, Ruby, PHP, etc.) to generate the HTML file that gets sent to the client; only your server-side knows your revision number or your checksum.  Once the server sends that html file with the "foo.js?x=12345" script tag in it, there is "client-side logic" in the sense that the user's browser decides whether to re-fetch that file or not based on what it sees in the HTML.