# Grails — CSS and JavaScript cache

Tags: javascript, css, caching, grails

When I make changes to CSS and JavaScript files, my users often have to reload a couple of times to get the changes (obviously to clear out the cache).

I was wondering if someone had a really good experience with a plugin to solve this issue.

I am currently using grails 1.3.7 and I use tomcat for my production environment.

Seems to me that [this](http://grails.org/plugin/cached-resources) might be the best option for me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164677/needed-advice-on-how-to-implement-js-css-versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the cached-resources plugin is a great option.

You need to install it alongside the [resources](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) plugin.  Assuming the resources plugin is installed and configured correctly, you don't have to do anything with the cached-resources plugin in order to get it to work correctly. Hence the apparent lack of documentation for the cached-resources plugin. Everything you need to know is linked from the resources plugin.

Comment: Thanks... I am going to move forward with that plugin